# Adobe flash download button redirects me to main site

Tags: firefox, flash

I want to update my flash version to 11.9.900.170.
Firefox's check for plugin updates redirects me to http://get.adobe.com/de/flashplayer/

If i click on `Install Now` i am redirected to www.adobe.com without a download.

How can this be fixed for future updates?

I am searching for a direct download from another server then adobes' at the moment.

Comment: Have you tried http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/otherversions/ you can use any browser to download it.

Comment: Then the button is grayed out directing to javascript:void(0)

Comment: @Wandang - You have to select the operating system and select either IE or "other browsers" before the button works.  I would use a **different** browser or disable ALL firefox extensions to download the file in question.

Comment: @techie007 that was the right call. instead of ghostery i use donottrackme. thanks, works now!